# White Screen After Unminimizing Java Window

Tags: java

I'm using LWJGL to make a small game, everything runs smooth and fine, but when I try to minimize and unminimize it, the screen just turns white and nothings shows up.

This is my main class:

```
package net.battleboy;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Main extends StateBasedGame {

    public static final String gamename = "Battle Boy 1.0 ALPHA";
    public static final int menu = 0;
    public static final int play = 1;
    public static final int settings = 2;
    public static final int LoadingScreen = 3;

    public Main(String gamename) {

        super(gamename);
        this.addState(new Menu(menu));
        this.addState(new Play(play));
        this.addState(new Settings(settings));
        this.addState(new LoadingScreen(LoadingScreen));

    }

    public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc)throws SlickException {

        this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
        this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
        this.getState(settings).init(gc, this);
        this.getState(LoadingScreen).init(gc, this);
        this.enterState(LoadingScreen);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        try {
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Main(gamename));
            appgc.setIcon("res/icon.png");
            appgc.setDisplayMode(840, 470, false);
            appgc.start();
        }catch(SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have 4 states and each of them seem to turn white.. Even when everything is being initialized.

Is there something I have missed when settings un my classes or is it something I did wrong?

(I'll post any other classes if needed)

Comment: I don't know LWJGL, but your problem seems to be that your application is not drawing again after being minimized and maximized.

Comment: How would I do that? And would it have to be in my main method? ...Or in each state?